# X-editable remove anchor if text is Empty

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I have a standard anchor href.. thats editable:

```
<a id="edit_790_67" class="editable editable-click" data-title="Name" data-url="ajax.php?a=common_name_add_edit" data-pk="790" data-type="text" href="#">Name test</a>
```

If I click to edit, and remove the text, the data will get deleted from the database.
I want to then remove/hide/display:none on anchor element with id #edit_790_67, so that its removed completely. I dont want Empty to appear.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

My code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#edit_790_67').editable({
            success: function(response, newValue) {
                $('#edit_790_67').editable('option', 'name', response);
                $('#edit_790_67').attr('id', response);
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
$('#edit_790_67').editable({
        success: function(response, newValue) {
                $('#edit_790_67').editable('option', 'name', response);
                $('#edit_790_67').attr('id', response);
        },
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                $(this).editable('option', 'url', null); // to prevent the ajax request to save data
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
});
```